# Insert text to selected JTextfield using JButtons

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield

I have multiple text fields and buttons

[image: Textfields]
[image: buttons]

When a text field is selected, text should be added to it when a button is pressed.

This is how I tried

```
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;
    private void num9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
            JTextComponent component = getFocuedComponent();
            component.setText( component.getText() + "9" );

    }
```

But it didn't work for me.

PS. Trying to make Matrix Calculator.

**EDIT :** for reference ... 
this how i implemented it ... after SJuan76's answer .... thanks!!

```
private JTextComponent selectedTextField;

// TextFields onFocus event
    private void a33FocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
        selectedTextField = (JTextComponent) evt.getSource();
    }
// action for button
        private void num9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
                selectedTextField.setText( selectedTextField.getText() + "9" );

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify the problem so I'll make a guess. If you want a better answer give a better question.

When you click in the button, the focus of the inputtext has already been lost (transferred to that button).

Add a listener to the text fields that update a shared variable, pointing to the last output text that was selected. When you process the actionevent, update that component.

Of course, there is the issue of resetting the shared variable when it no longer has sense.

UPDATE: I thought `getFocusedComponent()` was part of the API but I cannot find any reference to it, you should post more code if you want a good answer.

Comment: i understood the loosing focus thing but can you explain the next two lines with some code ... would be thankful ..

Comment: i found my mistake ... getFocuedComponent() is not any method ... i was asking is there any such method ... and i understood the two lines ... thank you for answering ..

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the selected JTextComponent as a class member. If you save  the selected component in a local variable (which is what I think you are doing), it doesn't remember the selected component.  A rough example:

```
public class YourClass  implements ActionListener
{
   private JTextComponent selectedTextField ; 
    ....
   void OnComponentSelected()
   {
     //init selectedTextField
   }
   void actionPerformed() 
   {
      //   selectedTextField.setText(...);
   }
}
```

Comment: The JTextComponent is not created in the method, it is not a local variable.

Comment: Look at his code, `void num9ActionPerformed`.. looks like a method to me.

Comment: And why do you think `getFocusedComponent()` is creating a new object? The logic would be that it is returning a reference to a component already in the container...

Comment: And where did I say he was "creating a new object". I said he isn't saving the selected component in a class member. When that method runs to completion, the selected component is forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

You can remember your last selected `JTextComponent` and change its text after pressing some button then. So you don't rely on focused component. You can remember it by listening to mouse events.